# performance of Intel TBB memory allocator?

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-management, tbb

once I tried TBB memory allocator in the project I was working on (MMORPG cluster, linux 2.6, recent gcc, 8 cores Intel Xeon) and was surprised when received worse performance. what can be a reason? I expected at least not better performance (all cores were loaded and allocation happens regularly). can anybody share own experience with TBB at all and its memory allocator in particular? tnx for your time

Comment: I haven't tried the TBB allocator, but you may also want to have a look at TCMalloc, which is often very fast and is designed to work well with thread-heavy programs.  It's part of the google-perftools package, BSD-licensed. http://code.google.com/p/google-perftools/  Docs on tcmalloc here:  http://google-perftools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/tcmalloc.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can probably get the best answers at [TBBs forums](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-threading-building-blocks/), they have excellent support.

I have been using TBB for a little over a year and I have been quite satisfied with TBB in general and its allocator.

You will need to provide more information, e.g. use case, numbers etc... otherwise it is impossible to tell what is causing your probelms.

Comment: big virtual world, ~20K actors, AI etc. central loop runs in parallel on all cores. communication is done by async messages. most activities is central loop and sending/receiving messages. synchronization is not perfect but all cores are ~75% loaded (according to `top` output). I haven't measured mem allocations frequency and volume, just did a quick test by linking with TBB, enabling its mem allocator and checking my overall performance. received ~5% of degradation.

Comment: Have you run a profiler on this, w and w/o tbb allocator? Would be interesting to see where the performance difference occurs.

Comment: nope, intel thread amplifier makes me crasy, tried also vTune, received some controversial results. any other good profilers? probably simpler in use